# C Binary File Reading: How many bytes should I move?

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fseek

Suppose I have a program that works with binary files in C language.

Suppose I have 8 objects (each object is a struct record type) in this binary file, and I have read the first 3 objects of the 8. (By reading 3 objects of the 8 I mean I have read it and store them into an array)

I know in order to read later content of the binary file, I have to use fseek call to achieve this goal. What I feel confused is this, suppose I want to read the 4th object of the 8, how many bytes/objects should I move/skip using fseek call?

Should I call

```
fseek(fp, sizeof(struct record) * 3, SEEK_SET);
```

or

```
fseek(fp, sizeof(struct record) * 4, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Did you experiment? You could have records with unique content and test what happens.

Comment: Please explain this `sizeof(struct record, SEEK_SET)`.

Comment: Is the second difference (3 vs 4) intentional? Is the first difference (above) intentional? Please elaborate what exactly you are asking about. Explain your reasoning behind both version.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, it should be `fseek(fp, sizeof(struct record), SEEK_SET * 3) `

Comment: If you think about it logically, to get the first record in the file you seek to position `0`. To get the second you seek to position `sizeof(struct record)`. Now how would you seek to the third record?

Comment: well, multiplying `SEEK_SET` by *anything* is *clearly utterly wrong* so the other one is probably more right.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree, but the "logic" behind "first at 0, second at `1*N`" is for people who already think the "C-ish" way.

Comment: No 3 vs 4 is not intentional, just random numbers. I did some experiment to my code but it behaves strangely, it didn't skip/move how many bytes as I wanted. 

What I am asking about is this, I want to purposely store the data in this binary file into several arrays, but as we all know before storing this data, I have to read first, but I have few experience working with binary file, so to be specific, I don't now how many bytes I should provide it to fseek in order to skip/move to the correct byte to read.

Comment: I think your question gets clearer, if you remove unintentional differences between "this or that". (Downvote not by me by the way.)

Comment: So does the first object in binary file always start at 0 byte? And the second object is at sizeof(my type) byte? Third object is at 2 * sizeof(my byte) byte?

Comment: @DigitalSoul correct - it is as simple as that. It's no different than an array in memory. First array-element is at offset zero. Second at 1 * sizeof(element). Thrid at 2 * sizeof(element).

Comment: You should not change your question to contain answers from comments, only change it to fix unintentional misrepresentation of what you are asking. See it this way: Now the question ONLY contains the unintentional difference. You are not at all asking about that...

Comment: Wait, or ARE you just asking about the `0,1,2,` vs `1,2,3,`? In that case good edit and it is just me getting confused by the history of edits.

Comment: The position of the first object in the file is obviously `sizeof(struct record) * 0`, the position of the second offset is `sizeof(struct record) * 1` etc. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's usually best to write these things down to get a sense of how the memory mapping works, so let's try and represent the file (assuming each struct is 4 bytes in size):

```
byte:   |A-0|A-1|A-2|A-3|B-0|B-1|B-2|B-3|C-0|C-1|C-2|C-3|D-0|D-1|D-2|D-3|E....
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
struct: | struct A      |struct B       |struct C       |struct D       |s...
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
address:0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10   11  12  13  14  15  16
```

as you can see from the visual representation, the file is 0-based indexed
i.e. the first struct is located at address 0 `(sizeof(struct record) * 0)`
the second is located at address 4 `(sizeof(struct record) *1)`
and so on...

from here one can derive for the nth element `offset = ( sizeof(struct record) * ( n - 1) )`

hope it makes it clearer...